# Draggabilly javascript call function not recognizing object

Tags: javascript, object, draggable

I have a Draggabilly item defined as follows;

```
var draggie = new Draggabilly( draggableElem, {
```

and

```
 draggie.on('dragEnd', function(e,p) {
```

I then have a number of processes that create the values for this function:

```
 function doOK (tLT, wird, fBBB, oBTS, dPs, m_data, innPs, count, HISTORY, HNT_1, HNT_2) {
```

I assume ( possibly wrongly) that the draggie can be used in the above function via:

```
let itemOK = doOK.call (draggie, tLT, wird, fBBB, oBTS, dPs, HM, innPs, count, HISTORY, HNT_1, HNT_2);
```

The function does indeed do all the various tasks, except when it gets to the final line:

```
draggie.disable();
```

when it reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: draggie is not defined
```

Why is this, and how do I disable the item so that it can no longer be moved?

Thanks you RudyW

I expected to be able to manipulate/change the settings/values in the draggie object so as to fix it to a location x,y and to prevent it being moved again (I have other functions for other moves).

If I add:

```
this.disable();
```

before the function, the item is disabled but it is at the end of the function that I need it to work. If I pass 'this' to the function I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.disable is not a function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. It's hard to tell how everything is connected from the way you've post bits and pieces.

Comment: Hi, there's a lot of code spread about to be able to do this in the space available.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to "freeze" the value of `draggie` and pass it as a parameter to a self invoking function wrapping your code.

```js
// btw, within the event listener you can 
// var draggie = $(this).data('draggabilly');

(function(draggie) {

  let itemOK = doOK.call(draggie, tLT, wird, fBBB, oBTS, dPs, HM, innPs, count, HISTORY, HNT_1, HNT_2);
  
})(draggie);
```